# modular curves over $\mathbb{C}$ as Riemann surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, modular-forms

Let $\mathscr{M}_*(N)$ be the Deligne Mumford stack of elliptic curves with the level $\Gamma_*(N)$.
($* = \varnothing, 0, 1$ or bal.$1$, see Katz-Mazur.)
Then this has the coarse moduli **scheme** $Y$ **over $\mathbb{Z}$**.
**(not complex manifold)**
I want to show that as Riemann surfaces, $Y(\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathbb{H}/\Gamma$, for suitable group $\Gamma$.
(e.g., $\Gamma(N) = \operatorname{ker}(\operatorname{SL}_2\mathbb{Z} \to \operatorname{SL}_2\mathbb{Z}/N), \Gamma_0(N) = \{ \gamma \in \operatorname{SL}_2\mathbb{Z} | \gamma \equiv 
$$\begin{bmatrix}* & *\\0 & *\end{bmatrix} \mod N \}$ etc.)

(Where by "the Riemann surface defined by an affine smooth algebraic variety $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$", I mean the Riemann surface induced by a closed immersion $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^N$ and the identification $\mathbb{A}^N(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C}^N$.
See appendix B in Hartshorne's AG.)

Here is what I have tried:
First, by the definition of coarse moduli and by some fundamental properties about classical modular forms (e.g., see theorem 1.5.1 of Diamond-Shurman's text), we have
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
|\mathscr{M}_*(N)(\mathbb{C})| @>{\text{bijective}}>> Y(\mathbb{C}) \\
@V{\text{bijective}}VV \\
\mathbb{H}/\Gamma.
\end{CD}

So if $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{C}$ (write it by $Z$) and if we have a map $\mathscr{M}_*(N) \to Z$, then $Y \cong Z$, and so as Riemann surfaces $Y(\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathbb{H}/\Gamma$.
(By the universal property of a coarse moduli, we have $Y \to Z$.
By above argument this is bijective on $\mathbb{C}$ rational points.
Thus is an isomoprhism, by Zariski Main theorem.)

Because $\mathbb{H}^*/\Gamma$ ($\mathbb{H}^*$ is the upper half plane with the cusps) is algebraic, it seems that $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$ is also algebraic.
However I have no idea how to get a map $\mathscr{M}_*(N) \to Z$.
(To define this map, by noetherian reduction and by the sheaf condition of representable functors on fpqc sites, it sufficies to define maps $\mathscr{M}_*(N)(S) \to Z(S)$ functorially for all affine scheme $S$ over $\mathbb{C}$ of finite type, I think.)

Thank you very much!

Comment: @reuns What you mean is "use the bijection $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma \cong $ (the set of the isom. classes of complex tori with a level) $: \tau \mapsto [\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_\tau, \text{ some level structure corresponding } \tau]$ as sets", right?   
I know, for example, $\tau \mapsto [\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_\tau, 1/N + \Lambda_\tau, \tau/N + \Lambda_\tau]$ gives a bijection for full level $N$ structure.
But from this arguments, I didn't understand the Riemann surface structure on $Y(\mathbb{C})$ at all.

Comment: The points of $\Gamma(N)\setminus \Bbb{H}$ give complex tori with full level $N$ structure through $\tau \to (1/N,\tau/N)\to\{ r(\Bbb{Z}+\tau \Bbb{Z},1/N+\Bbb{Z}+\tau \Bbb{Z},\tau/N+\Bbb{Z}+\tau \Bbb{Z}),r\in \Bbb{C}^*\}$. 
Then 
$\gamma\in\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\in GL_2^+(\Bbb{R})$ acts through $(1/N,\tau/N)\to (c\tau/N+d/N,a\tau/N+b/N)$ which corresponds to $\tau \to \frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d}$. If $\gamma\in SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ then it gives the same lattice, if it is in $\Gamma(N)$ then it sends the generators of the $N$-torsion to themselves. It translates to $y^2=4x^3-ax-b\to  y^2=4x^3-al^4 x-l^6b$

Comment: @reuns Thank you very much. I understand it. But I still don't understand why the analytic structure on $Y(\mathbb{C})$ coincides with $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$.
I think that the Riemann surface structure on $Y \times \mathbb{C}$ is induced by some closed immersion $Y \times \mathbb{C} \subseteq \mathbb{A}^N_\mathbb{C}$ and identification $\mathbb{A}^N(\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathbb{C}^N$.

Comment: Those things are very concrete. The map is given by the Weierstrass elliptic function and the Eisenstein series, it sends a complex torus and a point on it to an elliptic curve $E:y^2=4x^3-ax-b$ and a point on it. Multiplying the lattice by $r$ corresponds to $(x,y)\to (xr^2,yr^3)$. The only non-trivial step is to prove it is surjective, which follows from that integrating the holomorphic differential $dx/y$ on $y^2=4x^3-ax-b$ gives an isomorphism from the elliptic curve to a complex torus.

Comment: @k.j.: What are you reading? Your definition of a Riemann surface is very nonstandard (where did you find it?). The standard definition is that a Riemann surface is a 1-dimensional complex manifold. It is a theorem of Benke and Stein (1948) that every noncompact connected Riemann surface is Stein, more precisely,  admits a proper biholomorphic  embedding in ${\mathbb C}^n$ for some $n$.

Comment: @reuns Thank you. Maybe I could not convey well where I'm in trouble.
I know that for a lattice $\Lambda_\tau = \mathbb{Z} + \tau \mathbb{Z}$, the elliptic curve $y^2 = 4x^3 - g_2(\tau)x -g_3(\tau)$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_\tau$ as Riemann surfaces.
And conversely, for an elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{C}$, there exists $\tau \in \mathbb{H}$ such that $E(\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathbb{C}/\Lambda_\tau$.
(These are written in Silverman's AEC, I've read.)
(continue...)

Comment: And I know this correspondence gives the bijection from $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$ to the set of isom. classes of a pair of elliptic curve and a (for example) full level $N$-structure.
(This is theorem 1.5.1 of Diamond-Shurman.)   
What I cannot understand is, why this bijective map $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma \to Y(N)(\mathbb{C})$ is holomorphic.
Now $Y(N)$ is a priori just an algebraic curve.
So define the Riemann surface structure on it by $Y(\mathbb{C}) \subseteq \mathbb{A}^N(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C}^N$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I have studied some fondation of Riemann surfaces, so I know its definition ( = 1-dimensional complex manifold).
What I say is "the Riemann surface associated with a smooth affine algebraic curve over $\mathbb{C}$".
This is written in appendix B of Hartshorne's AG.
I define the coarse moduli scheme $Y$ as a "scheme", in particular not complex manifold.
So I asked "why this induced Riemann surface structure on $Y$ is the same as $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$?"

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify what you mean by $Y({\mathbb C})\cong {\mathbb H}/\Gamma$.

I assume that you mean that $\Gamma$ is a discrete **torsion-free** subgroup of $PSL(2, {\mathbb R})$.

Then for $N=1$ the modular curve is biholomorphic to ${\mathbb C}$ and, hence, is **not**  biholomorphic to the quotient of the hyperbolic plane by a discrete torsion-free subgroup of $PSL(2, {\mathbb R})$. (This is a consequence of the Liouville's theorem plus the covering theory.)

In contrast, for $N\ge 2$, $\Gamma(N)$ projects to a discrete torsion-free subgroup $\bar{\Gamma}(N)< PSL(2, {\mathbb R})$ and, hence, $Y({\mathbb C})\cong {\mathbb H}/\bar{\Gamma}(N)$. (The group $\Gamma(2)$ itself does have torsion, namely its center.)

More generally:

**Definition.** A Riemann surface $S$ is said to be of **hyperbolic type** (this terminology is not universally accepted) if $S$ is biholomorphic to the quotient 
${\mathbb H}/\Gamma$ where $\Gamma$ is a discrete torsion-free subgroup of $PSL(2, {\mathbb R})$.

The uniformization theorem implies that a connected Riemann surface $S$ is of hyperbolic type if and only if 
$\chi_{top}(S)<0$ (possibly $-\infty$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By $\Gamma$, I mean some subgroups of $\operatorname{SL}_2\mathbb{Z}$. I edited my question. Please check it.

Comment: Moishe means that we need that $\Gamma$ acts not only discretely but also without fixed point for $z\to \Gamma z$ to be a local chart of $\Gamma\setminus \Bbb{H}$ (the latter is the Riemann surface whose sheaf of holomorphic functions is the sheaf of $\Gamma$-invariant holomorphic functions on $\Bbb{H}$), with this assumption it is easier to prove the biholomorphism with the cubic curve side